# How to open particular link on clicking a image in java?

Tags: java, jtidy

I am using Jtidy parser to get the image from web page in java.

```
  URL url = new URL("www.yahoo.com");
  HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
  Document doc = new Tidy().parseDOM(in, null);
  NodeList img = doc.getElementsByTagName("img");
  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  list.add(img.item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue());
```

It is working fine,from above code I am getting the image. How to open the link "www.yahoo.com" on clicking that image in java?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague. I assume you're writing a Web application in java, so you may write a java servlet (or a JSP) whose output is an HTML page containing

```
<a href="http:/www.yahoo.com"><img src="your_image.gif"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a 1.6+ application, see `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URI)`.  For an application dpeloyed using webstart, see `BasicService.showDocument(URL)`.